# Why does "false; echo $?" return 1, if the Solaris source for false exits with 255?

Tags: bash, shell, solaris, opensolaris

I needed to find the source code for the implementation of the false. 
 I found sources on [github](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate) and found [false.c](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/false/false.c) where false exits with code 255. 
So, why does "false; echo $?" return 1 in shell instead of 255?
I think there is a source somewhere that I missed.

code from [false.c](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/false/false.c) file:

```
#pragma ident   "%Z%%M% %I% %E% SMI"

#include <unistd.h>

/*
 * Exit with a non-zero value as quickly as possible.
 */

int
main(void)
{
    _exit(255);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear how Illumos is related to Solaris. A more obviously Solaris-esque source would be https://github.com/kofemann/opensolaris/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/false/false.c

Comment: BTW, you can use `type false` to ask bash where the command `false` comes from, to determine whether it's defined by an external executable, a shell builtin, an alias, a function, etc.

Comment: POSIX merely mandates that `false` must return a non-zero exit code. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/false.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If bash is your shell, `false` is a builtin -- so you're looking at the wrong source code.

See instead the version built into bash itself, [in the file `builtins/colon.def`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/36f2c406ff27995392a9247dfa90672fdaf7dc43/builtins/colon.def#L44-L67):

```
/* Return an unsuccessful result. */
int
false_builtin (ignore)
     char *ignore;
{
  return (1);
}
```

If you want to use your OS vendor's version of `false` instead of the built-in one, you can do that with `command false` or `/bin/false`.

Comment: Oh sure, I got wrong. 

And I got another question. 
I tried `type false` as you said on comment and got `false is a shell builtin` also `type /bin/false` writes `false is /bin/false`. Are there 2 falses or is it just one?

Comment: Two: There's one built into the shell, and there's one provided by your operating system as an external binary. (If you have more than one shell installed on your system, they each may have a different built-in `false`; the only guarantee if it's a POSIX-compliant shell is that the behavior will comply with https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/false.html, specifying that it must return a "non-zero" value).